# Smoothing Data in Contour Plot with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, contour, smoothing

I am working on creating a contour plot using Matplotlib. I have all of the data
in an array that is multidimensional. It is 12 long about 2000 wide. So it is
basically a list of 12 lists that are 2000 in length. I have the contour plot
working fine, but I need to smooth the data. I have read a lot of
examples. Unfortunately, I don't have the math background to understand what is
going on with them.

So, how can I smooth this data? I have an example of what my graph looks like
and what I want it to look more like.

This is my graph:

[image: graph illustration]

What I want it to look more similar too:

[image: my goal]

What means do I have to smooth the contour plot like in second plot?

---

The data I am using is pulled from an XML file. But, I will show the output of
part of the array. Since each element in the array is around 2000 items long, I
will only show an excerpt.

Here is a sample:

```
[27.899999999999999, 27.899999999999999, 27.899999999999999, 27.899999999999999,
 28.0, 27.899999999999999, 27.899999999999999, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001,
 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001,
 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.0, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001,
 28.0, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001,
 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001,
 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001,
 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001,
 28.100000000000001, 28.100000000000001, 28.0, 27.899999999999999, 28.0,
 27.899999999999999, 27.800000000000001, 27.899999999999999, 27.800000000000001,
 27.800000000000001, 27.800000000000001, 27.899999999999999, 27.899999999999999, 28.0,
 27.800000000000001, 27.800000000000001, 27.800000000000001, 27.899999999999999,
 27.899999999999999, 27.899999999999999, 27.899999999999999, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0,
 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 27.899999999999999, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0,
 28.100000000000001, 28.0, 28.0, 28.100000000000001, 28.199999999999999,
 28.300000000000001, 28.300000000000001, 28.300000000000001, 28.300000000000001,
 28.300000000000001, 28.399999999999999, 28.300000000000001, 28.300000000000001,
 28.300000000000001, 28.300000000000001, 28.300000000000001, 28.300000000000001,
 28.399999999999999, 28.399999999999999, 28.399999999999999, 28.399999999999999,
 28.399999999999999, 28.300000000000001, 28.399999999999999, 28.5, 28.399999999999999,
 28.399999999999999, 28.399999999999999, 28.399999999999999]
```

Keep in mind this is only an excerpt. The dimension of the data is 12 rows by
1959 columns. The columns change depending on the data imported from the XML
file. I can look at the values after I use the Gaussian_filter and they do
change. But, the changes are not great enough to affect the contour plot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could smooth your data with a [gaussian_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

X, Y = np.mgrid[-70:70, -70:70]
Z = np.cos((X**2+Y**2)/200.)+ np.random.normal(size=X.shape)

# Increase the value of sigma to increase the amount of blurring.
# order=0 means gaussian kernel
Z2 = ndimage.gaussian_filter(Z, sigma=1.0, order=0)
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax.imshow(Z)
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax.imshow(Z2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The left-side shows the original data, the right-side after gaussian filtering.

Much of the above code was taken from the [Scipy Cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/SignalSmooth), which demonstrates gaussian smoothing using a hand-made gauss kernel. Since scipy comes with the same built in, I chose to use `gaussian_filter`.

Comment: I have looked at this example before. However, I am unable to get this to work on my array. I should note that my array is a python list not a numpy array. Would this cause problems? If so, what is the easiest way to convert a python list to a numpy array?

Comment: Hm, actually ndimage.gaussian_filter can operate on lists of lists just fine. (`ndimage.gaussian_filter(Z.tolist())` works, for example.) The problem must be elsewhere. Hard to say without seeing the data. What does not work mean? Is an exception raised? or does the result just not look right?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I believe it was an issue with the data being string in the lists. Though, the contour() function did not complain about it.

I got it to work without errors. But, it isn't changing the output of the contour() at all.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a short example of what your data looks like? Is it a list-of-strings or a list-of-list-of-strings, and are the strings string-representations-of-numbers, e.g. "1.5", or are they binary data that needs to be struct.unpacked?

Comment: I gave a brief excerpt up above. This is after I convert the string to floats.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried from .25 to 1,000 with the same results when I look at the contour. The order kwarg doesn't seem to make a large difference either.

Comment: Wait, there was an error in my code. (Hits head....)

I think it is working for now. I will not though, it doesn't really smooth out the jagged edges of the contour. As I raise the sigma values, it eventually just reduces the levels of contour produced from the data.

Answer (score 9):

One easy way to smooth data is using a [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) algorithm. One simple form of moving average is to calculate the average of adjacent measurements at a certain position. In a one-dimensional series of measurements a[1:N], for example, the moving average at a[n] can be calculated as a[n] = (a[n-1] + a[n] + a[n+1]) / 3, for example. If you go through all of your measurements, you're done. In this simple example, our averaging window has size 3. You can also use windows of different sizes, depending on how much smoothing you want.

To make the calculations easier and faster for a wider range of applications, you can also use an algorithm based on [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). The advantage of using convolution is that you can choose different kinds of averages, like weighted averages, by simply changing the window.

Let's do some coding to illustrate. The following excerpt needs Numpy, Matplotlib and Scipy installed. [Click here](http://www.nublia.com/dev/stackoverflow/stow_movingavg.py) for the full running sample code

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy
import pylab
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

def moving_average_2d(data, window):
    """Moving average on two-dimensional data.
    """
    # Makes sure that the window function is normalized.
    window /= window.sum()
    # Makes sure data array is a numpy array or masked array.
    if type(data).__name__ not in ['ndarray', 'MaskedArray']:
        data = numpy.asarray(data)

    # The output array has the same dimensions as the input data 
    # (mode='same') and symmetrical boundary conditions are assumed
    # (boundary='symm').
    return convolve2d(data, window, mode='same', boundary='symm')
```

The following code generates some arbitrary and noisy data and then calculates the moving average using four different sized box windows.

```
M, N = 20, 2000  # The shape of the data array
m, n = 3, 10     # The shape of the window array

y, x = numpy.mgrid[1:M+1, 0:N]
# The signal and lots of noise
signal = -10 * numpy.cos(x / 500 + y / 10) / y
noise = numpy.random.normal(size=(M, N))
z = signal + noise

# Calculating a couple of smoothed data.
win = numpy.ones((m, n))
z1 = moving_average_2d(z, win)
win = numpy.ones((2*m, 2*n))
z2 = moving_average_2d(z, win)
win = numpy.ones((2*m, 4*n))
z3 = moving_average_2d(z, win)
win = numpy.ones((2*m, 10*n))
z4 = moving_average_2d(z, win)
```

And then, to see the different results, here is the code for some plotting.

```
# Initializing the plot
pylab.close('all')
pylab.ion()
fig = pylab.figure()
bbox = dict(edgecolor='w', facecolor='w', alpha=0.9)
crange = numpy.arange(-15, 16, 1.) # color scale data range

# The plots
ax = pylab.subplot(2, 2, 1)
pylab.contourf(x, y, z, crange)
pylab.contour(x, y, z1, crange, colors='k')
ax.text(0.05, 0.95, 'n=10, m=3', ha='left', va='top', transform=ax.transAxes, 
    bbox=bbox)

bx = pylab.subplot(2, 2, 2, sharex=ax, sharey=ax)
pylab.contourf(x, y, z, crange)
pylab.contour(x, y, z2, crange, colors='k')
bx.text(0.05, 0.95, 'n=20, m=6', ha='left', va='top', transform=bx.transAxes, 
    bbox=bbox)

bx = pylab.subplot(2, 2, 3, sharex=ax, sharey=ax)
pylab.contourf(x, y, z, crange)
pylab.contour(x, y, z3, crange, colors='k')
bx.text(0.05, 0.95, 'n=40, m=6', ha='left', va='top', transform=bx.transAxes, 
    bbox=bbox)

bx = pylab.subplot(2, 2, 4, sharex=ax, sharey=ax)
pylab.contourf(x, y, z, crange)
pylab.contour(x, y, z4, crange, colors='k')
bx.text(0.05, 0.95, 'n=100, m=6', ha='left', va='top', transform=bx.transAxes, 
    bbox=bbox)

ax.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
ax.set_ylim([y.min(), y.max()])

fig.savefig('movingavg_sample.png')
# That's all folks!
```

And here are the plotted results for different sized windows: [image: Results]

The sample code given here uses a simple box (or rectangular) window in two dimensions. There are several different kinds of windows available and you might want to check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#High-_and_moderate-resolution_windows) for more examples.