# How to smooth matplotlib contour plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have numpy array with this shape: (33,10). When I plot contour I get ugly image like this:
[image]

while `contour()` doesn't seem to have any argument about smoothing or some sort of interpolation feature.

I somehow expected that tool which offers contour plot should offer smoothing too.
Is there straight forward way to do it in MPL?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, you need to interpolate your data.

There are a number of different ways to do this, but for starters, consider `scipy.ndimage.zoom`.

As a quick exmaple:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')

# Resample your data grid by a factor of 3 using cubic spline interpolation.
data = scipy.ndimage.zoom(data, 3)

plt.contour(data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! you always come up with something that I haven't heard before.

Comment: I just spend way too much time trying to make my figures as pretty as possible... Which probably explains why I never finish things on time! :)

Comment: I would use [griddata]( http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html).

Comment: @nicoguaro - The problem with using `griddata` is that it's intended for irregularly sampled inputs (i.e. scattered data).  For re-interpolating regularly gridded data there are different, much more efficient algorithms.  `scipy.ndimage.zoom` exploits the regularly gridded nature of the input.  It may not be obvious for a small input grid, but for larger grids, `zoom` can be several orders of magnitude faster.  However, if you don't have a regular grid to start with, then yes, `griddata` or something similar (e.g. `scipy.interpolate.Rbf`) is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Joe Kington, I will check `scipy.ndimage.zoom` to learn a little bit.

Answer (score 30):

In case your data is *sparse*, Joe Kingtons answer is great.

In case your data is *noisy*, you should consider filtering it instead:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
from matplotlib.pyplot import contour, show

sigma = 0.7 # this depends on how noisy your data is, play with it!
data = loadtxt('data.txt')
data = gaussian_filter(data, sigma)
contour(data)
show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

There is no easy way to get a smooth contour. An alternative is to try `imshow`. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8055489/302369) for other possibilities.

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

Z=np.loadtxt('data.txt')
plt.subplot(131)
plt.imshow(Z,interpolation='nearest')

plt.subplot(132)
plt.imshow(Z)

plt.subplot(133)
plt.imshow(Z,interpolation='gaussian')

plt.show()
```

[image]