# Matplotlib: Data cubic interpolation (or FIT) for Contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation, cubic

I have a series of data from device.
How can i make cubic interpolation or FIT for this plot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
b = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
c = [[3,2,1],[1,4,2],[4,5,1]]

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
fig1.set_size_inches(3.54,3.54)
#Create Contour plot
contour=ax1.contour(a,b,c)

plt.show()
```

Comment: maybe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12274529/832621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [adapt @Joe Kington's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12311139/832621) and use `scipy.ndimage.zoom` which for your case of a cubic interpolation fits perfectly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy.ndimage import zoom
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

# Receive standard Matplotlib data for 3d plot
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(1) # '1' is a step requested data

#Calculate smooth data
pw = 10 #power of the smooth
Xsm = zoom(X, pw)
Ysm = zoom(Y, pw)
Zsm = zoom(Z, pw)

# Create blank plot
fig = plt.figure()
#Create subplots
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
# Plotting
ax1.contour(X, Y, Z)
ax2.contour(Xsm, Ysm, Zsm)

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Excuse, this script does not start, but i found answer for my question! Tnx!

Comment: would you like to edit my answer with the modification you had to do? that would be nice for the next guy googling around up to this question...

Comment: Of course! I added a working code that perfectly demonstrates this technique. Tnx!