# Why aren't there lines between data points in Contourf plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I plotted a `contourf` plot with 9x11 points. When I plot the `contourf` plot then I expect to see lines between data points (since there is no other data in between the data points). But for example in the 0.9 level there are some parts (especially between x=2 and x=4) which are not linear. What can be the reason for that?

[image: Contourf plot]

```
plt.figure()
x=np.linspace(0,10,11)
y=np.linspace(0,10,11)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
levels = np.arange(0,1.01,0.1)
norm = cm.colors.Normalize(vmax=1, vmin=0)
cmap = cm.PRGn

CS1 = plt.contourf(X, Y, data,levels=levels,cmap=cm.get_cmap(cmap, 
        len(levels) - 1),norm=norm)
plt.xticks(np.arange(11),np.arange(11))
plt.yticks(np.arange(11),np.arange(250,855,55))
plt.xlim([0,8])
plt.colorbar(CS1)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: "there are some parts (...) which are not linear" - you mean the interpolation between them renders the line in a non-smooth way? Look into [interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274529/how-to-smooth-matplotlib-contour-plot).

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be that way: [`contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=contour#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf) colours in the area between the lines and [`contour`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=contour#matplotlib.pyplot.contour) draws the lines. See the [examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following plot helps to understand a contour plot better.

[image]

Here we plot a contour of an array with 3x3 points. The value of the middle point (`6`) is much larger than the other values. We chose levels of `3` and `5` where to plot the contour lines. Those lines are calculated by the contour as to interpolate the data.
Using more points will then allow to use more lines and make them look more smooth.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(3), np.arange(3))
Z = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,6,2],[1,1,1]])

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
cs = ax.contour(X,Y,Z, levels=[3,5])
cs2 = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, levels=[1,3,5,6], alpha=0.3)
plt.clabel(cs, cs.levels, inline=False)
plt.colorbar(cs2)
ax.scatter(X,Y)
for x,y,z in zip(X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), Z.flatten()):
    ax.text(x,y,z)

plt.show()
```