# Best way to plot a 2d contour plot with a numpy meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

i'm looking for the best way to create a contour plot using a numpy meshgrid.

I have excel data in columns simplyfied looking like this:

```
x data values: -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 ,3, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3
y data values:  1,  1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  2,  2,  2, 2, 2, 2, 2
z data values:  7 , 5,  6, 5, 1, 0, 9,  5,  3,  8, 3, 1, 0, 4
```

The x and y values define a 2d plane with the length (x-Axis) of 7 values and depth (y-Axis) of 2 values. The z values define the colour at the corresponing points (more or less a z-Axis).

I've tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]

y = [1,2]

z = [7,5,6,5,1,0,9,5,3,8,3,1,0,4]

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

A = np.array(z)
B = np.reshape(A, (-1, 2))

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.contourf(x, y, B)

plt.show()
```

I'm pretty sure i'm not getting how the meshgrid works. Do i have to use the whole List of x and y values for it to work?

How do i create a rectangular 2d plot with the length (x) of 7 and the depth (y) of 2 and the z values defining the shading/colour at the x and y values?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
x_, y_ = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z_grid = np.array(z).reshape(2,7)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.contourf(x_,y_,z_grid)
plt.show()
```

Edit: If you would like to smooth, as per your comment, you can try something like `scipy.ndimage.zoom()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274529/how-to-smooth-matplotlib-contour-plot), i.e., in your case

```
from scipy import ndimage

z_grid = np.array(z).reshape(2,7)
z_grid_interp = ndimage.zoom(z_grid, 100)
x_, y_ = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,3,z_grid_interp.shape[1]),np.linspace(1,2,z_grid_interp.shape[0]))
```

and then plot as before:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.contourf(x_,y_,z_grid_interp)
plt.show()
```

[image: image here]

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick response. It works but it seems like a contour plot isn't really what i'm looking for. It displays the data kinda ribbon-like (https://imgur.com/2MUDlbR). Do you or anyone else know a type of plot where it's shown a little more "round" or , let's say like a topography over the whole surface and that can be calculated with more or less the same format of data that i have here?

Comment: I have amended my post with a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way where you use the shape of the meshgrid (`X` or `Y`) to reshape your `z` array. You can, moreover, add a color bar using `plt.colorbar()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]
y = [1,2]
z = np.array([7,5,6,5,1,0,9,5,3,8,3,1,0,4])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
print (X.shape, Y.shape)
# (2, 7) (2, 7) Both have same shape
Z = z.reshape(X.shape) # Use either X or Y to define shape

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
plt.colorbar(ax1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: why I cant apply it when both x and y have same length. It says cannot reshape array of size 7 into shape (7,7)

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 3 )
y = np.linspace(0, 3, 4)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, cmap='RdGy');
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation for your answer. It will help to understand this better.