# How to apply kriging for 3D arrays in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, kriging

I have a 3D numpy array with some elevation values. I would like to apply kriging interpolation method to them and get a full valued array with same given shape.

My purpose is to create a surface actually. The values, I have, are hydrogelogical layers. Every layer from top to bottom are described with grid and I have some height values as described below. Nevertheless, I need height values for every grid.

For instance there is an array I have. "0" marks unknown values, others values are given values. `3 layer, 10 rows, 15 columns`:

```
[[[ 0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [11  9 11 11 10  9 11 11 11 11  9 11  11 11 9]
  [ 0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]

[[[ 0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [11  9 11 11 10  9 11 11 11 11  9 11  11 11 9]
  [ 0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]

[[[ 0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [11  9 11 11 10  9 11 11 11 11  9 11  11 11 9]
  [ 0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

I want to apply kriging to get interpolated values based on given values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [interpolate missing values 2d python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662180/interpolate-missing-values-2d-python)

Comment: @Nils Werner: kriging interpolation method is not available with NumPy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpolation over regular grid in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978052/interpolation-over-regular-grid-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it using Kriging algorithm. I showed an example in 2D [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892146/geographic-interpolate-in-python/64385792#64385792) using [OpenTURNS](http://www.openturns.org/) platform. It can be easily adapted in 3D.